# How do I get same hardware id as in UnityEngine.SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get the same hardware id in windows forms application that i get when i use `UnityEngine.SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier` in my game.

How can I get the same hardware id?

Comment: You dont, as it's undocumented. It only specifies: "On Windows Standalone System.deviceUniqueIdentifier returns a hash from the concatenation of strings taken from Computer System Hardware Classes", with a bunch of classes. The hash function itself is not documented and thus may change over time.

Comment: So what's the problem? If you need **exactly** the same hardware id - call `UnityEngine.SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`. If you need **your own** unique hardware id, just like one from Unity - use any hash function you like.

Comment: The problem is that if i don't get the same hardware id, i can't do proper verification in the game and server. You suggest `System.Managment`?

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm late but Unity's SystemInfo::deviceUniqueIdentifier is built like this:

Requires: `using System.Management;` in `System.Management.dll` (.NET Framework)

```
private string GetDeviceUniqueIdentifier() {
        string ret = string.Empty;

        string concatStr = string.Empty;
        try {
            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherBb = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
            foreach (var obj in searcherBb.Get()) {
                concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherBios = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
            foreach (var obj in searcherBios.Get()) {
                concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherOs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            foreach (var obj in searcherOs.Get()) {
                concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            ret = string.Join("", sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(concatStr)).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

I reverse engineered the Unity Editor to find out what it actually queries in the WMI.
This is obviously the Windows Implementation.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html

```
SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier
Leave feedback
public static string deviceUniqueIdentifier;
Description
A unique device identifier. It is guaranteed to be unique for every device (Read Only).

iOS: on pre-iOS7 devices it will return hash of MAC address. On iOS7 devices it will be UIDevice identifierForVendor or, if that fails for any reason, ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier.

Android: SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier always returns the md5 of ANDROID_ID. (See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID). Note that since Android 8.0 (API level 26) ANDROID_ID depends on the app signing key. That means "unsigned" builds (which are by default signed with a debug keystore) will have a different value than signed builds (which are signed with a key provided in the player settings). Also when allowing Google Play to sign your app, this value will be different when testing locally built app which is signed with the upload key and app downloaded from the Google Play which will be signed with the "final" key.

Windows Store Apps: uses AdvertisingManager::AdvertisingId for returning unique device identifier, if option in 'PC Settings -> Privacy -> Let apps use my advertising ID for experiences across apps (turning this off will reset your ID)' is disabled, Unity will fallback to HardwareIdentification::GetPackageSpecificToken().Id.

Windows Standalone: returns a hash from the concatenation of strings taken from Computer System Hardware Classes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389273(v=vs.85).aspx):
Win32_BaseBoard::SerialNumber
Win32_BIOS::SerialNumber
Win32_Processor::UniqueId
Win32_DiskDrive::SerialNumber
Win32_OperatingSystem::SerialNumber
```