# Unity select webcam by unique id

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam

I know that the webcam can be selected by name like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();

        if (devices.Length > 0)
        {
            webcamTexture.deviceName = devices[0].name;
            webcamTexture.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises when there are two webcams with the same name in the system. How can I select the other webcam in such case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get same hardware id as in UnityEngine.SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809274/how-do-i-get-same-hardware-id-as-in-unityengine-systeminfo-deviceuniqueidentifie)

Comment: Did you print out all device names and are sure there are two exactly identical?

Comment: @joreldraw This will give me the id but i cannot init the camera  inside unity using it :/

Comment: @derHugo Yes. Another case (which boils down to the same problem) is when the camera has special characters in its name.

Comment: use this id to name your decive with the uniqueId how you request for frontend but initialize the camera with her index

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use it like this.

```
void Start()
{
    WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    WebCamTexture webcamTexture1 = new WebCamTexture();
    WebCamTexture webcamTexture2 = new WebCamTexture();

    if (devices.Length > 0)
    {
        Cam1 = devices[0].name; 
        Cam2 = devices[1].name;
        
        webcamTexture1.deviceName = Cam1;
        webcamTexture2.deviceName = Cam2;
        
        webcamTexture1.Play();
        webcamTexture2.Play();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if it helps your use case specifically.

And regarding special character, it might be useful to see this thread : [WebCam with no name](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1407313/webcam-with-no-name.html)