# Why unique Id using System.Management and SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier in Unity are different?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, unity-game-engine, uniqueidentifier

I have a specific problem with distinguishing computers. I want to get the same unique Id values in my Unity app and in my WPF app. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809274/how-do-i-get-same-hardware-id-as-in-unityengine-systeminfo-deviceuniqueidentifie) post I took the code

```cs
private string GetDeviceUniqueIdentifier() {
        string ret = string.Empty;

        string concatStr = string.Empty;
        try {
            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherBb = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
            foreach (var obj in searcherBb.Get()) {
                concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherBios = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
            foreach (var obj in searcherBios.Get()) {
                concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherOs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            foreach (var obj in searcherOs.Get()) {
                concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            ret = string.Join("", sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(concatStr)).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

for my WPF side and I have *SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier* for my Unity side. On my computer these things return the same values, but when I tested it on quite weak PC, they returned different values:
WPF side retured *5f5ea7e20b798fc1c16a7c65747f58e50519cb76* and
Unity side returned *c23be19b361fcc9683c544358cea150695ac74ca*. I use *2021.2.14f1* version of Unity.
What could be the reason of this? Or is there other ways to have the same unique Ids in .NET Framework and in Unity?

I found out that `ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard")` and `ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS")` return *Not Applicable*. This is quite strange. I also tried to use *string.Empty* instead of them, but Ids are still different.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution, but I'm not sure, that it is stable solution. As I said:

> I found out that ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard") and ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS") return Not Applicable. This is quite strange. I also tried to use string.Empty instead of them, but Ids are still different.

And I almost gave up, but tried the last one thing:

```cs
private string GetDeviceUniqueIdentifier() {
        string ret = string.Empty;

        string concatStr = string.Empty;
        try {
            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherBb = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
            foreach (var obj in searcherBb.Get()) {
                concatStr += obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value.ToString().Trim() ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherBios = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
            foreach (var obj in searcherBios.Get()) {
                concatStr += obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value.ToString().Trim() ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using ManagementObjectSearcher searcherOs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            foreach (var obj in searcherOs.Get()) {
                concatStr += obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value.ToString().Trim() ?? string.Empty;
            }

            using var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            ret = string.Join("", sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(concatStr)).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

I added `.Trim()` at the end of each statement and this solved my problem. Now my *Unity* Id is equal to *.Net Framework* Id. Hope this will help someone.