# How to calculate the same deviceUniqueIdentifier as Unity does for linux?

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, uid

I want to create a class library using C# (would be a part of Avalonia app) that is going to calculate the same `deviceUniqueIdentifier` as Unity' `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier` does. I know how to do this for Windows - using *System.Management* library and [there](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html) is also the parameters written that should be used to calculate the uid (there is also the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436982/why-unique-id-using-system-management-and-systeminfo-deviceuniqueidentifier-in-u)).
So the problem that the is no a word about how does the Unity do it on linux. The main question is how to calculate the **same** uid using C# for linux?

Comment: Is Linux supported? It's not mentioned in the API so I would expect to get the unsupported identifier .. the summary of the duplicate basically is: It is not documented -> how should we know? ;) Only option would be to decompile the Linux Unity core and dig through the c++/IL2CPP code

Comment: @derHugo Quite funny summary. There is a [blog](https://www.itcodar.com/csharp/how-to-fast-get-hardware-id-in-csharp.html) where you can see that linux is also supports *deviceUniqueIdentifier*. There are also lots of thread where people discuss *deviceUniqueIdentifier* on linux. I know that the Unity docs are not full but is that the reason that noone knows how to do this.